# AEM 6.3, wcm.io: register (Mock)ResourceResolverFactory issue

Tags: mocking, adobe, aem, sling

I am using wcm.io to create an AEMContext and I am able to the a simple Sling model that has no reference to other services. I do want to add a reference to my AliasService so I register/activate it in my context setup:

```
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new AliasService());
```

AliasService:

```
public class AliasService {

@Reference
private AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory resourceResolverFactory;

...
```

As you can see this service has a reference to AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory so I register/activate is as well:

```
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory.class, new AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory());
```

AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory:

```
public class AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory {

@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory delegate;

...
```

The service depends on ResourceResolverFactory so I inject/activate it using the 'MockResourceResolverFactory' (final list of injects):

```
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, new MockResourceResolverFactory());
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory.class, new AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory());
aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new AliasService());
```

I now get the following error if I try to execute my test:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: args must be an even number of name/values:[org.apache.sling.testing.resourceresolver.MockResourceResolverFactory@7fb95505]
```

[image]

I have no idea how to fix this or what is causing this, all help is greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE**

The fix Jens provided totally worked for my older services (Felix annotation based -> org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component). When I try this for a newer service (OSGI annotation based -> org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component), I get an error.

Service:

```
...
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(service = TestService.class, immediate = true, property = {
    Constants.SERVICE_DESCRIPTION + "=" + "Test Service",
    Constants.SERVICE_VENDOR + "=" + BundleConstants.SERVICE_VENDOR
})
public class TestServiceImpl implements TestService {

@Override
public String getValue() {
    return "test-value-from-service";
   }
}
```

Sling Model:

```
@OSGiService
private TestService testService;

public String getValue(){
   return testService.getValue();
}
```

Register:

```
TestService testService = aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new TestServiceImpl());
```

Error:

Caused by: org.apache.sling.testing.mock.osgi.NoScrMetadataException: No OSGi SCR metadata found for class com.asadventure.core.service.TestServiceImpl

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I am seeing the same error for newer services. Having to resort to reflection to set the fields :(

Comment: You should check my newer post, I got it working now: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671484/aem-6-3-maven-bundle-plugin-automate-osgi-scr-metadata-for-osgi-annotated-class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to bother with the `ResourceResolverFactory`. It is already registered in the `AemContext`.

This should be the solution for your problem:

```
public class AliasServiceTest {

    @Rule
    public final AemContext aemContext = new AemContext();

    @Test
    public void testAliasService() {
        // This will register your Resource Resolver Factory. This should work 
        // because the referenced (Sling) Resource Resolver Factory is already 
        // registered in the "aemContext". Therefore, all references are satisfied
        // and the service should be activated.
        aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory());
        AliasService service = aemContext.registerInjectActivateService(new AliasService());

        service.callSomeMethod();
    }

}
```

You can move the registration of your `AutoClosableResourceResolverFactory` to a "set up" method that is annotated by `@Before`. This way you do not have to this for every test. Alternatively, you can build your own context (which I suspect you are already doing judging by the stacktrace in your image) and register the service there.

Furthermore, it seems that your code has an error:

```
registerInjectActivateService(ResourceResolverFactory.class, new MockResourceResolverFactory());
```

As far as I can tell there is no method signature that takes the `Clazz` as first argument and the `service instance` as second argument.

See: http://wcm.io/testing/aem-mock/apidocs/org/apache/sling/testing/mock/osgi/context/OsgiContextImpl.html

It is one of the following:

```
registerInjectActivateService(T service)
registerInjectActivateService(T service, Map<String,Object> properties)
registerInjectActivateService(T service, Object... properties)
```

Where `T service` is your actual service instance and the (optional) second argument is used for configuration. This configuration would be passed in the `activate` method of your service.

Comment: You are totally right, everything is working now. But I do have a question left. My AliasService uses the 'org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component' annotation but newer services should use OSGi annotations (org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component). Can you check the update in my original ticket for the problem I am having now (only for the newer code)

Comment: @Jdruwe Can you please create another question for your second issue. That topic is too big to also discuss here.

Comment: You are right :) -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48671484/aem-6-3-wcm-io-service-test-not-working-using-osgi-annotations

Comment: @Jdruwe did my answer here help you and is "right"? If so please accept the answer so that other Stackoverflow user know that this is the "right" answer.

Comment: Yes It did sorry :D My new question is also resolved my unit tests now work.