# AEM 6.3, maven-bundle-plugin automate OSGi SCR metadata for OSGi annotated classes

Tags: mocking, adobe, aem, sling

I am trying to unit test my OSGI R6 annotated classes. I found out that I have to specify some info in the maven-bundle-plugin: http://felix.apache.org/documentation/faqs/apache-felix-bundle-plugin-faq.html#use-scr-metadata-generated-by-bnd-in-unit-tests --> Use SCR metadata generated by BND in Unit Tests.

If I invalidate cache in Intellij and restart and try to execute my test again it fails. If I manually trigger the manifest goal of the maven-bundle-plugin and run the test it succeeds, can I automate the generation of the metadata?

Will this configuration still work for tests that are written for classes using the older felix src annotations?

Comment: "but my felix ones give me the same old error" - what do you mean? could you re-write your question to only include exactly what you are asking for ?

Comment: You are right, I just did so.

Comment: "invalidate cache in Intellij" meaning what? also, how *exactly* do you run your tests? The bottom line is, the metadata have to be generated before tests run which is what the instructions in the link you provided do. When running unit-tests via maven and ultimately on your CI/CD does it succeed? or fail?

Comment: Invaliding the cache just clears out all 'temp files' for example the generated metadata. When I right click on the class and select 'Run Tests' they fail but even when I use 'mvn clean install' I get the same error complaining about the missing metadata for my OSGI annotated class.

Comment: After building the project on the command line using `mvn clean install` please check if the SCR files were generated. You would fine them in `target/classes/OSGI-INF`. The steps explained in the page you linked should solve the issue.

Comment: @Jdruwe At this point, the only way we can help is if you can create a new project with only a simple service and unit-test that replicate the issue you are seeing, push that project to github so we can take a look.

Comment: I was missing <exportScr>true</exportScr>

Comment: @Jens After adding the exportScr property the SCR files are generated under target/classes/OSGI-INF but when I enable my maven-surefire-plugin (remove skipTests property) the test fail because the SCR files are missing (they are cleared at the beginning of each clean install). Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: @Jens I see the following in the logging but only SCR generation for the felix annotated classed: [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:3.5.0:manifest (scr-metadata) @ aem-company-platform-core-bundle --- ...

Comment: @Jens I found out that the default LifecyclePhase is set to PROCESS_CLASSES for the ManifestPlugin. I manually set it to '<phase>generate-test-resources</phase>' and now it works. Any idea why it does not work for the process-classes lifecycle? Is there some kind of conflict with maven-scr-plugin that also generates SCR files at the process-classes lifecycle?

Answer (score 2):

I forgot `<exportScr>true</exportScr>` in the maven config. Now I only have to run my test later in the lifecyle as explained here: https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/aem-project-archetype/blob/8aecf81ea5bb897a7d8dd5f241d5fcd561c36aa6/src/main/archetype/it.launcher/pom.xml and all will be good.